# Is this correct or is there a better way?

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a c program that reads a barcode(that is 10 digits long) from stdin, adds up the first 9 digits of the barcode, and if the second digit of the sum of the 9 digits is equal to the 10th digit in the barcode it writes the barcode to stdout.

Here is what I have so far, can some one please help me or tell me what wrong with what i've got or what to add. would it be possible to put the whole barcode into a character array and sum the first 9 digits and compare it to the value of bar[9]? how would i do this?
Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
  int sum = 0;
  char bar[10];
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    scanf("%d", &bar[i]);
  }

  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
     sum += bar[i];
  }

  if(sum[1] == bar[10]){
      return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: First thing to note: for loop condition mismatch. one more `scanf()` needed in/out side the loop.

Comment: `sum[1]` is invalid, so as `bar[10]`

Comment: This is not compilable code, but beyond that issue, you are trying to sum the integer equivalent of the `char` value, which is **not** the same as the integer itself. If you don't know what that means, do a `printf()` statement in the second `for` loop and print out the value of `bar[i]`.

Comment: I edited the question, hopefully not making a mistake in adding the closing curly bracket. At least `bar[10]` is invalid, because `bar[9]` is the last element.

Comment: Do you get build errors? Please include them complete and unedited. Do you get unexpected output? Then tell us the input and the expected and actual output. Does it crash? Then run in a debugger and tell us where in your code the crash happens.

Comment: Please try to summarize your real question in the question title. This one here is just completely useless.

Answer (score 0):

*CORRECTIONS*

1. change char bar[10] to int bar[10], because you are just handling intergers
2. Array indexes begin from 0 and end at `SIZEOFARRAY-1`
3. primitives like `int`, `float` variables cannot be referred using indexes like you have done in `sum[1] == bar[10]`. here sum is just an int type where as bar is an array of integers.
4. logic to test the last but 2 digit and the tenth digit of barcode

   ```
   int secondDigit = sum%100; // for 189 this resturns 89
   secondDigit = secondDigit/10 // for 89 this return 8

   if(secondDigit == bar[9]) // see SIZEOFARRAY which is 10 - 1 = 9 will be the last array element. 
   {
        // as you wanted display the barcode.
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here sum is an integer not an array .

I am considering your specific case to add 9 digits . Since the sum of 9 digits can't cross 81. The second digit will be

```
  int secondDigit = sum /10 ;
```

If you check this with bar[9], you will get the answer. Need to note that the tenth digit in an array is array[10-1] since the index starts from zero.

You need to sum from 0th index to 8th index to calculate sum of 9 digit

```
   for(i=0;i<9;i++) { 
       sum += bar[i];
     }
```

Comment: say the barcode is 9999999991 the first nine digits will add to 81 and the 10th digit which is 1 is equal to the second digit of the sum(81) therfore the barcode is valid. but if i do what you told me that would be 81/10 =8.1=8(b/c of int)? not 1.

Comment: I calculated the second digit from the unit's place. If you want the second digit then use secondDigit = sum %10 . modulo operator. And also integer division will result in integer not a float . So 81/10 will be 8 since you have declared sum as integer.

Answer (score 0):

1] You got three error in the code, you need to take a mod (%) to cut the second digit of the sum.

2] You are not reading the 10th digit from bar-code reader

3] bar[10] is not the 10th digit. Its bar[9] as indices start from 0 in c

apart from these, some suggestions below

You can optimize the code by merging the first two loops. Since its an embedded system, its important

I would limit the number of returns to one by keeping return status in a variable. It makes the code more readable.

I would suggest the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int sum = 0,i;
    char bar[10];

    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
       scanf("%d", &bar[i]);
       sum += bar[i];
    }

   scanf("%d", &bar[i]);

   if( (sum % 10) == bar[9 ])
   {
      return 1;
   }

   return 0;

}
```